# Subscription is not populating in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have created Azure Build Pipeline and now want to create the Release Pipeline. On the release tab, I am unable to see any subscription whereas I do have subscription which I can use in the Portal.azure.com.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Subscription is not populating in Azure Release Pipeline

There is no such Subscription in the Azure realease pipeline tab directly.

To use the subscription in the release pipeline, we need to create a service connection to connect the azure Portal via subscription:

Project Settings-> Service connections-> Azure Resource Manager:

[image]

Then we could use this connection for the task, like Azure CLI:
[image]